# How to make plug-in data APKs?

Tags: android

My goal is to have a main application and a selection of independent separate data packs, which are available on demand as APK and have their own entry in the Play Store each. It's completely up to the user which, and how many, of these they care to install. Think language packs, keyboard layouts, dictionaries, this sort of thing. The application would always check what data packs are installed and give the user the choice of which one to use.

I thought that the data APKs would not provide any activities but would contain a `Service` that allows access to a `ContentProvider` of some sort. But it's all new to me and there's a lot of terminology that confuses me: is this a [`receiver`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element)? A [`provider`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element)? Both of these seem to fit my purpose to some extent. Do I need to have this service (one per data pack) run in the background, waiting for broadcast calls, or can I just somehow inform Android it exists, so it would launch it when this particular query comes from my application?

It would be ideal if nothing would have to be run in the background, possibly even during the listing phase. Then one data file would be chosen and the corresponding APK would only run for as long as the data is being accessed. All the data packs are of the same sort (dictionaries) and need not provide any further functionality than to provide some static metadata and then give access to a raw file.

All of the information I could find relates to "extension APK"s but that's orthogonal to what I want.

Comment: I wish I could add a bounty because I'm looking for the exact same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that the data APKs would not provide any activities but would contain a Service that allows access to a ContentProvider of some sort.

You do not need a `Service` to provide access to a `ContentProvider`.

> is this a receiver? A provider?

I do not know what "this" is in that sentence. A `ContentProvider` uses a `<provider>` element in the manifest. A `Service` uses a `<service>` element in a manifest.

> Do I need to have this service (one per data pack) run in the background, waiting for broadcast calls, or can I just somehow inform Android it exists, so it would launch it when this particular query comes from my application?

None of the above. Your main app finds out about the existence of these "data pack" APKs via `PackageManager`. For example, you might use a standard naming convention for the application ID/package names for those "data pack" APKs, then use [`getInstalledPackages()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages(int)) to find out which "data pack" APKs are installed.

From there, you could:

- [Use `createPackageContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createPackageContext(java.lang.String,%20int)) to access assets and resources in the "data pack"
- Generate a `Uri` pointing to the "data pack" APK's `ContentProvider`, then use a `ContentResolver` to access content published by the APK (e.g., `openInputStream()`, `query()`)
- Use other forms of IPC (broadcasts, started services, bound services) to interact with the "data pack"

> All the data packs are of the same sort (dictionaries) and need not provide any further functionality than to provide some static metadata and then give access to a raw file.

I do not know why you would distribute this material in the form of APK files via the Play Store. Just download the material from your own Web server, in some convenient format (e.g., ZIP archive).

Comment: Thank you! Per last question: I don't have a web server and am not thinking of paying for one for the purposes of one free application. I tried using a friend's one in the past but this was a source of undiagnosable errors, down times beyond my control, differences per Android version (permissions) etc. Moreover, it's nice that if the data are APKs, the user has a simple, familiar way of installing and uninstalling them, leaving no dead weight on the device. I have seen this pattern used in some other apps, just didn't know how they did it.